# When is it safe to call dispatch_io_close() when using Grand Central Dispatch?

Tags: macos

My app copies files using the `dispatch_io_read()` and `dispatch_io_write()` methods provided by Apple's Grand Central Dispatch on OSX 10.10.

I provide my users with a 'cancel' button. I have implemented this in various ways using `dispatch_io_close(channel, DISPATCH_IO_STOP)`, but every method I have tried results in occasional crashes with messages such as "BUG IN LIBDISPATCH: Over-release of an object", "BUG IN LIBDISPATCH: Resurrection of an object" or a similar crash relating to retain/release problems.

I get the same type of crash if I simply `close()` the file descriptors of the files I am reading/writing when the user hits 'cancel', or if I call `dispatch_io_close(channel, DISPATCH_IO_STOP)` from within the cleanup handlers of `dispatch_io_read()` and `dispatch_io_write()`.

How do I safely cancel my GCD IO operations?

Comment: It's not really possible to answer your question without seeing you existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you might write a simple replacement for `cat` using dispatch io:

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    dispatch_io_t stdin_io = dispatch_io_create(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, STDIN_FILENO, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int error) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening stdin: %d\n", error);
        exit(error);
    });

    dispatch_io_t stdout_io = dispatch_io_create(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, STDOUT_FILENO, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int error) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening stdout: %d\n", error);
        exit(error);
    });

    dispatch_group_t io_completion_group = dispatch_group_create();

    dispatch_group_enter(io_completion_group);
    dispatch_io_read(stdin_io, 0, SIZE_MAX, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
        if (error) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Read error: %d\n", error);
            exit(error);
        }

        dispatch_group_enter(io_completion_group);
        dispatch_io_write(stdout_io, 0, data, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t data, int error) {
            if (error) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Write error: %d\n", error);
                exit(error);
            }

            if (done) {
                dispatch_group_leave(io_completion_group);
            }
        });

        if (done) {
            dispatch_group_leave(io_completion_group);
        }
    });

    dispatch_group_notify(io_completion_group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        dispatch_io_close(stdin_io, 0);
        dispatch_release(stdin_io);

        dispatch_io_close(stdout_io, 0);
        dispatch_release(stdout_io);

        dispatch_release(io_completion_group);

        exit(0);
    });

    dispatch_main();
}
```

Hopefully that can serve as a starting point for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a semaphore to prevent closing until the read operation is complete; you can safely close the channel afterwards. Here's a snippet that shows you how to do this for write operations (although it can be easily used the same way for read operations):

```
size_t length = width * height * 4;
void *tdata = malloc(length);
[texture getBytes:tdata bytesPerRow:rowBytes fromRegion:MTLRegionMake2D(0.0, 0.0, width, height) mipmapLevel:0];
            dispatch_data_t data = dispatch_data_create(tdata, length, NULL, DISPATCH_DATA_DESTRUCTOR_DEFAULT);
NSString *outputTextureFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", frame];
NSString *outputTextureFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/PinHoleTemp/%@", [outputTextureFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"dat"]]];

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

dispatch_io_t write_channel = dispatch_io_create_with_path(DISPATCH_IO_STREAM, [outputTextureFilePath UTF8String], 1, O_WRONLY, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(int error) {

                                                                 });

dispatch_io_write(write_channel, 0, data, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(bool done, dispatch_data_t  _Nullable data, int error) {
        if (done) NSLog(@"Finished writing data to file");
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        });

dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


    dispatch_io_close(write_channel, 0);
```

This example writes a data file containing a Metal texture to a file at the specified URL each time a video frame is acquired by the camera. Once the texture is created, it is converted to a dispatch_data_t object. Then, a semaphore is created, and is used to block any creating and opening a new channel and write operations until it is done. After the semaphore has been signaled by the dispatch_io_write completion handler, the code executes the dispatch_io_close block.